# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi ícono forme parte del select y despliegue las opciones normalmente?

Tags: html, css

Tengo mi select con un **ícono de material icons de google**, al crear el select me doy cuenta de que o bien al agregar un z-index al select o al icono, **la parte del ícono ya no es seleccionable o ya no forma parte del select** y tampoco despliega las opciones del select, solo el área que está el select, ¿Cómo puedo hacer que esa área del ícono tambien forme parte del select y al hacer click en el ícono se desplieguen las opciones normalmente?.

**Adjunto mi código no funcional**

```css
.checkout-information__form--input input::placeholder {
  color: #828282;
}
.checkout-information__form--input--location {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  border: 0.1rem solid #828282;
  border-radius: 1.2rem;
  padding: 1.2rem 1.4rem 1.2rem 1.2rem;
  position: relative;
}
.checkout-information__form--input--location span {
  color: #828282;
  margin-right: 1.2rem;
}
.checkout-information__form--input--location--select {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
.checkout-information__form--input--location--select select {
  color: #828282;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  appearance: none;
}
.checkout-information__form--input--location--select span {
  color: #828282;
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  margin-right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1.2rem;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
          content="ie=edge">
    <title>Checkout Page</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon"
          href="devchallenges.png"
          type="image/x-icon">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
          rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<div class="checkout-information__form--input--location--select">
                                <select name=""
                                        id="">
                                    <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
                                    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                                    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
                                    <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
                                    <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
                                    <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
                                    <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
                                    <option value="Antigua & Barbuda">Antigua & Barbuda</option>
                                    <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
                                    <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
                                    <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
                                    <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
                                    <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
                                    <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
                                    <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
                                    <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
                                    <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
                                    <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
                                    <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
                                    <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
                                    <option value="Belize">Belize</option>
                                    <option value="Benin">Benin</option>
                                    <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
                                    <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
                                    <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
                                    <option value="Bonaire">Bonaire</option>
                                    <option value="Bosnia & Herzegovina">Bosnia & Herzegovina</option>
                                    <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
                                    <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
                                    <option value="British Indian Ocean Ter">British Indian Ocean Ter</option>
                                    <option value="Brunei">Brunei</option>
                                    <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
                                    <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
                                    <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
                                    <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
                                    <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
                                    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
                                    <option value="Canary Islands">Canary Islands</option>
                                    <option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
                                    <option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
                                    <option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
                                    <option value="Chad">Chad</option>
                                    <option value="Channel Islands">Channel Islands</option>
                                    <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
                                    <option value="China">China</option>
                                    <option value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option>
                                    <option value="Cocos Island">Cocos Island</option>
                                    <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
                                    <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
                                    <option value="Congo">Congo</option>
                                    <option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option>
                                    <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
                                    <option value="Cote DIvoire">Cote DIvoire</option>
                                    <option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
                                    <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
                                    <option value="Curaco">Curacao</option>
                                    <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
                                    <option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
                                    <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
                                    <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
                                    <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
                                    <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
                                    <option value="East Timor">East Timor</option>
                                    <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
                                    <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
                                    <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
                                    <option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
                                    <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
                                    <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
                                    <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
                                    <option value="Falkland Islands">Falkland Islands</option>
                                    <option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
                                    <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
                                    <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
                                    <option value="France">France</option>
                                    <option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
                                    <option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>
                                    <option value="French Southern Ter">French Southern Ter</option>
                                    <option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
                                    <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
                                    <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                                    <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
                                    <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
                                    <option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
                                    <option value="Great Britain">Great Britain</option>
                                    <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
                                    <option value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
                                    <option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
                                    <option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
                                    <option value="Guam">Guam</option>
                                    <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
                                    <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
                                    <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
                                    <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
                                    <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
                                    <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
                                    <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
                                    <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
                                    <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
                                    <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
                                    <option value="India">India</option>
                                    <option value="Iran">Iran</option>
                                    <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
                                    <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
                                    <option value="Isle of Man">Isle of Man</option>
                                    <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
                                    <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
                                    <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
                                    <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
                                    <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
                                    <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
                                    <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
                                    <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
                                    <option value="Korea North">Korea North</option>
                                    <option value="Korea Sout">Korea South</option>
                                    <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
                                    <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
                                    <option value="Laos">Laos</option>
                                    <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
                                    <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
                                    <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
                                    <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
                                    <option value="Libya">Libya</option>
                                    <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
                                    <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
                                    <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
                                    <option value="Macau">Macau</option>
                                    <option value="Macedonia">Macedonia</option>
                                    <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
                                    <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
                                    <option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
                                    <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
                                    <option value="Mali">Mali</option>
                                    <option value="Malta">Malta</option>
                                    <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
                                    <option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
                                    <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
                                    <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
                                    <option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
                                    <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
                                    <option value="Midway Islands">Midway Islands</option>
                                    <option value="Moldova">Moldova</option>
                                    <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
                                    <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
                                    <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
                                    <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
                                    <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
                                    <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
                                    <option value="Nambia">Nambia</option>
                                    <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
                                    <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
                                    <option value="Netherland Antilles">Netherland Antilles</option>
                                    <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands (Holland, Europe)</option>
                                    <option value="Nevis">Nevis</option>
                                    <option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
                                    <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
                                    <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
                                    <option value="Niger">Niger</option>
                                    <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
                                    <option value="Niue">Niue</option>
                                    <option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
                                    <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
                                    <option value="Oman">Oman</option>
                                    <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
                                    <option value="Palau Island">Palau Island</option>
                                    <option value="Palestine">Palestine</option>
                                    <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
                                    <option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
                                    <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
                                    <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
                                    <option value="Phillipines">Philippines</option>
                                    <option value="Pitcairn Island">Pitcairn Island</option>
                                    <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
                                    <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
                                    <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
                                    <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
                                    <option value="Republic of Montenegro">Republic of Montenegro</option>
                                    <option value="Republic of Serbia">Republic of Serbia</option>
                                    <option value="Reunion">Reunion</option>
                                    <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
                                    <option value="Russia">Russia</option>
                                    <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
                                    <option value="St Barthelemy">St Barthelemy</option>
                                    <option value="St Eustatius">St Eustatius</option>
                                    <option value="St Helena">St Helena</option>
                                    <option value="St Kitts-Nevis">St Kitts-Nevis</option>
                                    <option value="St Lucia">St Lucia</option>
                                    <option value="St Maarten">St Maarten</option>
                                    <option value="St Pierre & Miquelon">St Pierre & Miquelon</option>
                                    <option value="St Vincent & Grenadines">St Vincent & Grenadines</option>
                                    <option value="Saipan">Saipan</option>
                                    <option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
                                    <option value="Samoa American">Samoa American</option>
                                    <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
                                    <option value="Sao Tome & Principe">Sao Tome & Principe</option>
                                    <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
                                    <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
                                    <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
                                    <option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
                                    <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
                                    <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
                                    <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
                                    <option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
                                    <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
                                    <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
                                    <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
                                    <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
                                    <option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
                                    <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
                                    <option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
                                    <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
                                    <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
                                    <option value="Syria">Syria</option>
                                    <option value="Tahiti">Tahiti</option>
                                    <option value="Taiwan">Taiwan</option>
                                    <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
                                    <option value="Tanzania">Tanzania</option>
                                    <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
                                    <option value="Togo">Togo</option>
                                    <option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
                                    <option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
                                    <option value="Trinidad & Tobago">Trinidad & Tobago</option>
                                    <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
                                    <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
                                    <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
                                    <option value="Turks & Caicos Is">Turks & Caicos Is</option>
                                    <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
                                    <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
                                    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                                    <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
                                    <option value="United Arab Erimates">United Arab Emirates</option>
                                    <option value="United States of America">United States of America</option>
                                    <option value="Uraguay">Uruguay</option>
                                    <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
                                    <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
                                    <option value="Vatican City State">Vatican City State</option>
                                    <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
                                    <option value="Vietnam">Vietnam</option>
                                    <option value="Virgin Islands (Brit)">Virgin Islands (Brit)</option>
                                    <option value="Virgin Islands (USA)">Virgin Islands (USA)</option>
                                    <option value="Wake Island">Wake Island</option>
                                    <option value="Wallis & Futana Is">Wallis & Futana Is</option>
                                    <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
                                    <option value="Zaire">Zaire</option>
                                    <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
                                    <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
                                </select>
                                <span class="material-icons">expand_more</span>
                            </div>
              
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La verdad es que los elementos select son difíciles de poder editar y de agregarles estilo propio con CSS, ya que están llegando desde el sistema operativo en lugar de ser generados únicamente por el navegador, como la mayoría de los otros elementos HTML en cualquier página web, si quisiéras saber más te dejo este link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Advanced_form_styling (en inglés) pero te extraigo lo más importante acerca de lo que dice del select:

```
Algunos elementos no pueden ser estilizados usando CSS. Estos incluyen:

    Elementos que crean widgets desplegables, incluyendo <select>, <option>, <optgroup> y <datalist>.
```

## Alternativa #1

Te dijera, mejor usa jQuery o Javascript para que puedas realizar un comportamiento similar de un menú desplegable pero ahora tienes otra alternativa más sencilla que se llama AlpineJS, este framework minimal te permite crear muchas utilidades comúnes como por ejemplo un menú desplegable, la habilidad de mostrar ó esconder elementos, utiliza Javascript pero de una forma bastante sencilla y como primer acercamiento (o no necesariamente) te conviene aprender ya que no necesitas declarar muchas funciones, te he creado un CodePen para que puedas ver como llegue a lo que tu quieres hacer. https://codepen.io/eduardonwa/pen/ZELZaOG

Te explico más a detalle como podemos hacer esto:

1. Primero necesitamos un "contenedor" al que le atribuiremos "x-data", en este podemos iniciar nuestro componente AlpineJS que se llamará **open**, por default queremos que no se vean las opciones de la lista, así que le ponemos **false**:

`<div x-data="{ open: false }">`

2. Después tenemos que hacer uso de cualquier elemento HTML que nos sirva como "activador" del componente, con un `<button>` podemos pasarle un `eventListener` y le decimos que escuche al evento de **click**, al hacer esto podemos definir el comportamiento del botón, como queremos hacer que se parezca a la de un select necesitamos hacer un "toggle". Con una operación ternaria le decimos que si "open" es "falso" que sea activado, y ya que lo tenemos por default en este estado, la operación será "true", y con esto obtendremos el comportamiento de poder abrir o cerrar en ambos casos.

`<button x-on:click="open = ! open">`

3. Por último nos queda seleccionar nuestra lista, y seleccionar el objeto que se podrá ver o esconder, nos vamos al `<ul>` y asignamos lo siguiente: `x-show="open"`.
4. La parte que dice `x-on:click.away="open = false"` es simplemente que al hacer click afuera del elemento la lista se esconderá, muy parecido al de un select.
5. Puedes ver que inserté un elemento SVG dentro del botón y puedo estilizar dicho vector (SVG), aquí con Tailwind le cambie el alto, el ancho y el color usando algunas propiedades de SVG y clases de Tailwind.

En el CodePen utilizo TailwindCSS pero esto no es requerido ni necesario es solamente un ejemplo para que puedas ver que usando AlpineJS podemos crear un menú sin necesidad de complicarse tanto.

## Alternativa #2

Ahora bien, tal vez no quieras utilizar un elemento `<ul>` para realizar una lista y eso también es válido, pero si realmente quiziéras seguir utilizando el select, puedes insertar un elemento SVG e incluirlo en tu select desde tu CSS.

Lo incluímos como una imagen de fondo y ya que podemos utilizar CSS en elementos SVG, de aquí es sencillo poder posicionarlo, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background: transparent;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg fill='black' height='55' viewBox='0 0 24 24' width='55' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='M7 10l5 5 5-5z'/><path d='M0 0h24v24H0z' fill='none'/></svg>");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: 100%;
  background-position-y: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}
```

Utilizando la propiedad `url()` y luego declarando que lo que queremos es un SVG, podemos atribuírle un alto, un ancho e incluso el color con la propiedad **fill**, podemos también posicionar nuestro dibujo utilizando propiedades CSS ya que podemos hacer uso completo de CSS:

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg fill='black' height='55' viewBox='0 0 24 24' width='55' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='M7 10l5 5 5-5z'/><path d='M0 0h24v24H0z' fill='none'/></svg>");
```

```
  background-position-x: 100%;
  background-position-y: 0px;
```

Es importante que sepas (si es que no lo sabes ya) que **viewBox** funciona como nuestra "caja" en el que el vector se encuentra, cada número corresponde a una propiedad:

```
viewBox = "min-x min-y ancho alto"

Valores:

    min-x: Es usado para el axis en horizontal. Es para que nuestro SVG se pueda mover de una forma horizontal (derecha a izquierda).
    min-y: Es usado para el axis en vertical. Es para que nuestro SVG se pueda mover de una forma vertical (arriba ó abajo).
    width: Esta se refiera para el ancho de nuestra caja.
    height: Esta se refiera para el alto de nuestra caja.
```

## Alternativa #3

Esta viene más a favor en cuanto a la experiencia de usuario y simplemente usando un `cursor:pointer` en el select es como podemos decirle al usuario que "aquí" podemos hacer "clic", pudieras dejar el ícono o no, esa sería tú decisión.

Nota: aquí te dejo una librería de íconos SVG que puedes consultar: https://www.zondicons.com/icons.html puedes copiar el ícono abriendo tu pestaña de "Inspector" (si utilizas Firefox) `ctrl + shift + I` seleccionas el elemento SVG, presionas clic derecho, y luego copiar/Copiar HTML externo y se te copiará el SVG a tu portapapeles, es algo que utilizo con frencuencia y te la recomiendo. Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias colega, respuestas muy acertadas para mi problema.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la etiqueta `label` en html cuando trabajas con `input`/`select` (para tener este [efecto](https://twitter.com/i/status/1387158982905708545)):

```css
.my-custom-select {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  color: #828282;
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

.my-custom-select select {
  color: #828282;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  appearance: none;
}

.my-custom-select label {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1.2rem;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.my-custom-select span {
  border-radius: .4rem;
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

/* Esto no es necesesario y puede borrarse */
.my-custom-select:focus-within {
    border: red solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="my-custom-select">
    <select id="my-select">
        <option>A1</option>
        <option>A2</option>
        <option>A3</option>
    </select>
    <label for="my-select">
        <span class="material-icons">
            expand_more
        </span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Puedes apreciar que desde un navegador de escritorio no se muestran las opciones, solo hace `focus` en el `select`, pero si presionas <kbd>Space</kbd> puedes hacer que se muestren las opciones.

Sin embargo en otros navegadores como en Safari para ios si se muestran al darle click en tu icono:

[image: safari-ejemplo]

Considerado eso puedes decidir si vale la pena usar un simple `select` con su `label` o no en tu proyecto.

---

Si no quisieras usarlo: podrías usar un *dropdown* (como el de Bootstrap) y así te evitas *inventar la rueda*, ejemplo:

> Lo malo es que si tu proyecto no tiene Bootstrap, agregarlo solo para una parte no tiene mucho caso a menos de que uses Webpack para solo importar lo que necesites.

```css
.material-icons {
    position: absolute;
    right: .4rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary w-100 d-flex justify-content-center" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown
        <span class="material-icons">
            expand_more
        </span>
  </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu w-100" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
        <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button></li>
        <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button></li>
        <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, la cuestión es que es únicamente una práctica, los estilos son únicos sin bootstrap para ese select, por lo que si el usuario se guía por el icono tratara de aplastarlo, pero si no le salen las opciones no es muy funcional, mi código es por eso que requiero ayuda :(